# Program does not print out integers except for one

Tags: java

So I made this program before without the methods and it worked. However, I made the methods and then things stop working. The only line that works is the print array and greaterThanAverage. I will show the original code in case anyone wants to see it. The program only prints 0 for every other thing.

```
public static void printArray (int n)
{
  int[] arr = new int[n];
  System.out.println("Array on one line: ");
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
     arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 500) + 1;
     System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
  }
}
public static void getMax(int n)
{  
  int[] arr = new int[n];
  int max = arr[0];

  for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
     if(arr[i] > max)
     {
        max = arr[i];
     }
  }
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Maximum: " + max);
}
public static void getMin(int n)
{
  int[] arr = new int[n];
  int min  = arr[0];

  for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
     if(arr[i] < min)
     {
        min = arr[i];
     }
  }
     System.out.println("Minimum: " + min);
}
public static void getAverage(int n)
{
  double x = 0;
  double y;
  int[] arr = new int[n];
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++)
  {
     x = arr[i] + x;
  }
     y = x / arr.length;
    System.out.println("Average: " + y);
}
public static void sumValues(int n)
{
  int sum = 0;
  int[] arr = new int[n];
  for(int num : arr)
  {
     sum = sum + num;
  }
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
}
public static void greaterThanAverage (int n)
{
  int[] arr = new int[n];
  int count = 1;
  double y;
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++)
  {
     {         
        count ++;              
     }   
  }       
     System.out.println("Number of integers greater than average: " + count);
}
public static void countInc (int n)
{
  int[] arr = new int[n];
  int count2 = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
  {       
     if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1])
     {         
        count2++;
     }
  }
     System.out.println("Number of times subsequent value increases: " + count2);
}
public static void countDec (int n)
{
  int[] arr = new int[n];
  int count3 = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
  {
     if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
     {
        count3 ++;
     }
  }
     System.out.println("Number of times  subsequent value decreases: " + count3);
}
public static void printArray3PerLn (int n)
{
  System.out.println("Array with 3 elements per line: ");
  int[] arr = new int[n];
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  { 
     System.out.print(arr[i]+ " "); 
     if(i % 3 == 2)
     {
        System.out.println();
     }
  }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
   int sum = 0;
   int n;
   do
   {
     System.out.print("Enter integer n, greater than 0: ");
     n = kbd.nextInt();
     }  while(n < 1);      
     System.out.println();

     printArray(n);

     getMax(n);

     getMin(n);

     sumValues(n);

     getAverage(n);

     greaterThanAverage(n);

     countInc(n);

     countDec(n);

     printArray3PerLn(n);
 }
}
```

Comment: You're creating a new empty array, in each method, I'd guess that is not what you want

Comment: In almost all of the methods, you create a new array but you don't put any numbers in it. Because of this, the array will just contain zeroes. You'll have to put some numbers in the arrays in each of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

**It is because you are not filling arrays with numbers**

```
**public static void  countDec (int n)
{
  int[] arr = new int[n]; -<<**
```

example if u call the method 
countDec(5);
It will fill this array with 0 not with random numbers as u did in the printArrayMethod

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 public static void getAverage(int n)
    {
    double x = 0;
    double y =0;
    anArray = new double[n];
        for(int i=0;i<anArray.length;i++)
        {
            anArray[i] = randomFill();
        }
    for(int ji = 0; ji < anArray.length; ji ++)
      {
         x = arr[ji] + x;
      }
         y = x / arr.length;
        System.out.println("Average: " + y);
    }
```

Method for random Numbers

```
public static double randomFill(){

    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt();
    return randomNum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are recreating a new local array inside each method instead of passing an array you create once as an argument to each method. To rectify this, create a method to create and return your array from an integer size and change the method signature of each of your other methods to have an int array as a parameter.

See the working code here: https://ideone.com/ycZbNX

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EntryPoint{
    public static int[] getArray(final int n) {
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 500) + 1;
        }
        return arr;
    }
    public static void printArray(final int[] arr) {
        System.out.println("Array on one line: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }
    public static void getMax(final int[] arr) {
        int max = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > max) {
                max = arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Maximum: " + max);
    }
    public static void getMin(final int[] arr) {
        int min = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] < min) {
                min = arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Minimum: " + min);
    }
    public static void getAverage(final int[] arr) {
        double x = 0;
        double y;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            x = arr[i] + x;
        }
        y = x / arr.length;
        System.out.println("Average: " + y);
    }
    public static void sumValues(final int[] arr) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int num: arr) {
            sum = sum + num;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
    }
    public static void greaterThanAverage(final int[] arr) {
        double average = 0;
        for(int num: arr){
            average += num;
        }
        average /= arr.length;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i] > average){
                ++count;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of integers greater than average: " + count);
    }
    public static void countInc(final int[] arr) {
        int count2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1]) {
                count2++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of times subsequent value increases: " + count2);
    }
    public static void countDec(final int[] arr) {
        int count3 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                count3++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number of times  subsequent value decreases: " + count3);
    }
    public static void printArray3PerLn(final int[] arr) {
        System.out.println("Array with 3 elements per line: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
            if (i % 3 == 2) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int n;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter integer n, greater than 0: ");
            n = kbd.nextInt();
        } while (n < 1);
        System.out.println();
        final int[] arr = getArray(n);
        printArray(arr);

        getMax(arr);

        getMin(arr);

        sumValues(arr);

        getAverage(arr);

        greaterThanAverage(arr);

        countInc(arr);

        countDec(arr);

        printArray3PerLn(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that says "Illegal static declaration in inner class Problem18.Main"

Comment: @Richard Could you please provide a reproducible example? I can't see what your code looks like. The code I have currently provided executes fine.

Comment: I was using the code from the website that's why I got the error. But I used the code you used here.

Comment: can I ask why you used **(final int[] arr)** when you named every method?

Comment: @Richard If you went to https://ideone.com/ycZbNX, you would see that my code runs fine. What is your exact problem? What is the error message?